# How to initialize a python class variable outside of functions?

Tags: python, oop

I have a python function:

```
class MyClass:
   my_class_variable: str = Optional[None]

   @classmethod
   def initialize(cls):
      cls.my_class_variable = cls.some_function()
```

I plan to use it like:

```
x = MyClass.my_class_variable
```

How can I guarantee have `my_class_variable` to have initialized with a value, eg how can I force call `initialize()` ?

Comment: by defining it inside the __init__ method you're made sure to call the init method every time you start. Init runs first and then all the other class functions run.

Comment: @Red they want `my_class_variable` to be a _class_ variable, `__init__` only works with _instances_

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to refer to class methods when defining class variables in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54621348/how-to-refer-to-class-methods-when-defining-class-variables-in-python)

Comment: @Red no, that is only if you create an instance

Comment: @PranavHosangadi well, you *can* create a class variable in `__init__`, nothing will stop you

Comment: Anyway, the way to guarantee is simply to write `MyClass.initialize()` after your class definition.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga but __init__ will only get run if i try to get an instance, eg MyClass(), but i only plan to use MyClass without instance. Also how can I run initialize without an handle on cls outside of functions?

Comment: @user1008636 I think you meant to respond to Red with regards to `__init__`. In any case, as I already pointed out, the simplest way to guaratnee `initialize` has been called is *to call it*. So after the class definition for `class MyClass`, just write `MyClass.initialize()` after.

Answer (score 0):

you could do something like :

```
def dec(cls):
    cls.my_class_var = cls.some_func()
    return cls
@dec
class MyClass:
    my_class_var = ""

    @classmethod
    def some_func(cls):
        return "Cool :)"

print(MyClass.my_class_var) --> Cool :)
```

Another option would be to use a metaprogramming, but as long as there is only one simple thing to do, I would use a decorator :)